# Sorted list of strings? Find length of list without using length function

Tags: java, string, sorting

Given a sorted list of strings and the last entry is null. You cannot use the list.length to determine the length of the list, but come with an approach efficient than O(n) to find the end Index of list or length of list?

Comment: Smells like homework. What have you tried so far? The Stack Overflow community is glad to help, but never gives answers.

Comment: Homework by any chance? What *are* we allowed to use?

Comment: @Nico, We give answers all the time.

Comment: "an approach efficient than O(n)" means nothing in English. What do you mean? "as efficient as", "at least as efficient as", "more efficient than", etc.

Comment: @Nico A Q&A site without A would be worthless ;)

Comment: @cularis & little bunny foo foo - Sure, to people who have actually tried something. The common practice is **not** to give answers to homework questions without the person actually trying something. Unless you were joking, in which case lol :)

Comment: @cularis unless it's [Philosophy SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) :D

Comment: @Nico your statement just sounded so final: "STACKOVERFLOW NEVER GIVES ANSWERS!" Shaded got me :(

Comment: Hahaha! Yeah, *never* was maybe a bit strong xO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast and dirty, but it should get things done.

This is just like a guess a number scenario. Start with an arbitrarily large number.

1. While key exists, double. Once IndexOutOfBounds is thrown, continue to step two.
2. Does that index exist?

   - Yes, then halve the difference between the next know number above the current index and add to the current index.
   - No? Then halve the difference between the next know number below the current index and the current one.

The good news? This is O(logn). The bad news? You have a potential of having logn/2 exceptions.

Comment: This sounds like its O(logn) where n = arbitrary number and not the size of the list.

Comment: Start with index 1 and double if you find a non-null entry.  That way it will be O(log(n)) where n = list size.

Comment: Starting at index zero or one and doubling can be slow if it's a LinkedList:  Each "get" call is O(N).  (ArrayList.get is O(C), where "C" is a constant.)

A binary search down from Integer.MAX_VALUE will probably have the same problem because each of the "hits" will be costly.

Comment: But it isn't a linked list, it is a string or a chr[].

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework.

Look at List.iterator() and the Iterator interface.

Answer (score 0):

Using a binary search will give you O(logn)

So just search for the null entry :)

Comment: So, where do you start to search if you cant use the length-attribute?

Comment: You're right. I didn't think of that. So I guess since you have to start at the first element, you couldn't use binary search at all could you?

Comment: You can still do it.  I don't like that this is almost certainly a homework question, so I'm not going to post the answer here, but send me a note if you're curious and can't figure it out :)  Edit: looks like someone did post the approach I was thinking of.  Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

Easy:  Use the 'List.size()' method.  The Java 'List' interface does not have a "length" field or property.

> ;->